# Get Firefox 4 css for alerts

Tags: css, firefox, alert

Firefox 4 has its own css style that applies when an alert is on the screen. I'd like to know how to get/know the style in order to apply to my javascript alerts.

Comment: Styling `alert` and `confirm` windows could as well become security issue of some sort because if you could style them you could make confirm windows more appealing to users hence more likely to confirm them and engage in some doom's day scenario...  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't: alerts are system-specific dialog boxes and it depends on browsers and OSes what they look like. I know Firefox 4 uses a custom, non-blocking kind of dialog, but you can't style alerts yourself.

Comment: @antoni: This could as well become security issue of some sort because if you could style them you could make confirm windows more appealing to users hence more likely to click them...

Comment: Uhm, @Robert, agreed, but Antoni isn't in these comments, you should post this as a comment to his own question.

Comment: @Marcel: Why? My comment was just complementing your answer. And since I referenced him, he will get informed in his inbox.

Comment: @Robert: No, see [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) “Notifications apply to the author, commenters, and editors of the question or answer that you are commenting on—users not in that list cannot be notified. The question and answers are all considered independently. For example, if Alice was the author of, commented on, or edited the question or her answer, then you cannot notify her by commenting on Bob's answer (unless Alice *also* participated in that answer), and vice versa.”

Comment: That's a nice link. Every day is a good opportunity to learn something new. I simply thought that @name will notify the person.

Comment: @Robert: No, that's why I asked [Always notify the OP when @OP's-user-name is mentioned in comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/52376/always-notify-the-op-when-ops-user-name-is-mentioned-in-comments) (and to be frank, I'm a bit surprised a 13K user didn't know this).

Comment: @Marcel: Never bothered with these details. I rather answer questions and ask my own. You should check [my meta reputation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/137977) that's a better indicator of such knowledge. Mine is rather low. But I obviously did it fine most of the time. (which will now immensely improve thanks to you). ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the DOM Inspector to inspect the element. I think through that you can see the styles of anything in the chrome layer of Firefox.

And the comments above @Robert antoni didn't say he wanted to change the styles, just use them for his own dialog.

Comment: I'd only need to know the style, then i'd apply to my custom dialogs with jquery. In fact they are very simple and not complex so it doesnt' matter how exactly firefox renders them. I made the question because I thougt that there was a css style that could be downloaded. Thank you everybody!!